# Get Activity object from Custom Preferences

Tags: android

I am trying to integrate facebook-connect to my android application. All the examples i am seeing over the internet are creating the connection from an Android activity. I am doing something a bit different, the user can configure its connection to facebook from a custom preference. I was successfull when doing it for twitter and foursquare. However, the method Facebook.authorize requires an Activity as parameter, and since i am inside a preference, i am not able to find any reference to an activity object.

So my question here is, how to get a reference for an activity inside a preference?

Thank you all
T

Comment: Could you post a small amount of code - just enough to illustrate what you have attempted so far?

Comment: Richard... i manage to fix it. I just applied a cast to the context object (Activity) context and it worked fine. Not sure this is the correct way to achieve this, but as far it works, im fine! Thank you

Answer (score 9):

I was able to get the Activity reference by casting the Context object to an Activity.

```
Activity activity = (Activity) context;
```

or with a custom activtity you can also do this

```
SettingsActivity activity = (SettingsActivity) context;
```

Comment: Not always, e.g. see this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7378644/how-to-call-getwindow-outside-an-activity-in-android/26871793#26871793)

Answer (score 4):

It's an old question, though I use following function with the `com.android.support:preference` preferences fragment:

```
public static Activity getPrefActivity(Preference pref)
{
    Context c = pref.getContext();
    if (c instanceof ContextThemeWrapper)
    {
        if (((ContextThemeWrapper) c).getBaseContext() instanceof Activity)
            return (Activity) ((ContextThemeWrapper) c).getBaseContext();
    }
    else if (c instanceof Activity)
        return (Activity) c;
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an activity called `MyActivity`, can you just use `MyActivity.class`?

Comment: I tried this... and i am getting an error message like this one: "The method authorize(Activity, String[], int, Facebook.DialogListener) in the type Facebook is not applicable for the arguments (Class<CustomPreferencesActivity>, String[], int, FacebookPreference.FbLoginDialogListener)"... and my call to that method is like this "mFacebook.authorize(CustomPreferencesActivity.class, ApplicationData.FACEBOOK_PERMISSIONS, -1, new FbLoginDialogListener());"