# getWindow() method not able to use

Tags: android, android-canvas, lockscreen

I have created a lockscreen for ics which will replace the default lockscreen. In my code I want to use `getWindow()` method to set the `"android:hardwareAccelerated"` true for increasing the efficiency.

I don't have any activity in the **LockScreen.java**. So I am not able to use `activity.getWindow()`.
I tried with `context.getWindow()` and `this.getWindow()` also. But still it shows error. How to use `getWindow()` method to get the Window object?

Comment: maybe this help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7378644/how-to-call-getwindow-outside-an-activity-in-android

Comment: +1 for your question, I have the same problem, have you solved it already?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is simply method **you can call on Activity** or class that extend it, because it belongs to it.. :S So either you need to be in activity or you need to pass that activity somehow.
and I don't get it how you don't have any Activity?! You would need to have some in this case...

LockScreen is extending some class, no? Which one?